# WP&woocommerce CSS img sizes clash in footer

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I have two images in my footer.php, they are hard coded and shall stay that way:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" height="30"> is an  
<a href="https://www.#.com" target="_blank" ><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/img/logob.png" height="30">
```

on the woocommerce pages, for some reason, these two logos show really big(original size). It seems, inspection it, that my 30px are being overwritten by woocommerce.css:

```
.woocommerce img, .woocommerce-page img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

}

I have tried to change this in my custom.css to get my small images back to:

```
.woocommerce img, .woocommerce-page img {
height: 30px;
max-width: 100%;
```

}

But this causes all images on the page to shrink, any idea how I can tell my custom.css to keep the images zsizes int he footer ANYWHERE on the page?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no class or id to select that image you wanted so I saw you have an attribute in your image tag which is `height="30"`, It can be used as a selector to just select this image, not the others. Here is what you can do to select it:

`.woocommerce img[height=30], .woocommerce-page img[height=30] { height: 30px; max-width: 100%;}`

Comment: Thank you , tried did not work, but gave me the right idea to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I added a `.smallfooter` class to the image in `footer.php`, now it is working fine on all pages. I had called the class `.small` before, this was overwritten by the bootstrap css for some reason, hence giving it a new unique class `. smallfooter` did it!